# How to set android application "type"?

Tags: android

Is there a way to set your applications "type"? For example, If I download Opera for Android and then in another application I click a web URL, Android will ask me do I want to open the link with the default browser or with Opera. How do Opera achieve this?

**EDIT** specifically, how would I pass the URL into my activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about activities and intent-filters.

Here is a good starting point: [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html), and specifically [Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Declaring) section.

Comment: But how would I pass the URL into my activity?

Comment: It will be passed in `Intent` that your `Activity` can get using `getIntent()` function. But you should really read documenation. This is the first thing any android developer should be familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

This is done via the mechanism of Itent filters, that are defined in your Manifest.xml.
I think Opera has probably an intent filter like this set on the main activity :

```
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Then when the opening of a web page is requested via  a sent Intent, the system will search through its database, which application can answer it and propose the applications to the user.

Comment: But how would I pass the URL into my activity?

Comment: Yea as inazaruk answered you, this is passed in the Intent that your activity answers to. The url can be retrieved by calling in your activity : getIntent().getData(). But you should find all this information in the android developer documentation. You can also use ddms to see what is passed into the sent intent, watch for a line saying : ActivityManager Starting: Intent {act=...VIEW dat=http://... ...}

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to study intent-filters. Here is the short text from android docs.

*"Components advertise their capabilities — the kinds of intents they can respond to — through intent filters. Since the Android system must learn which intents a component can handle before it launches the component, intent filters are specified in the manifest as  elements. A component may have any number of filters, each one describing a different capability."*

Specifically for a browser I suppose that you have to register it like below:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="http"/> 
    </intent-filter>
```